# How to use dynamic tag names in ASP.net configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, config

I'm trying to use asp.net configuration support to read and write a custom section in below format.

```
<ApplicationSettings>
    <LogFactory>
      <LogToDataBase>True</LogToDataBase>
      <LogToFile>False</LogToFile>
    </LogFactory>
    <PingPongModule>
      <UsePerformanceCounters>True</UsePerformanceCounters>
      <SaveMessagesToDatabase>True</SaveMessagesToDatabase>
    </PingPongModule>
    ..
    <AnyComponentName>
      <AnyConfigName>ConfigValue</AnyConfigName>
    </AnyComponentName>
  </ApplicationSettings>
```

But according to what I currently know, I should use something like below format to use custom configuration section support. I'm familiar with parsing below format.

```
<ApplicationSettings>
    <Components>
      <Component Name="LogFactory">
        <ConfigElements>
          <ConfigElement Key="LogToDataBase" Value="True"></ConfigElement>
        </ConfigElements>
      </Component>
      <Component Name="PingPongModule">
        <ConfigElements>
          <ConfigElement Key="UsePerformanceCounters" Value="True"></ConfigElement>
          <ConfigElement Key="SaveMessagesToDatabase" Value="True"> </ConfigElement>
        </ConfigElements>
      </Component>
      ..
      <Component Name="AnyComponentName">
        <ConfigElements>
          <ConfigElement Key="AnyConfigName" Value="ConfigValue"></ConfigElement>
        </ConfigElements>
      </Component>
    </Components>
  </ApplicationSettings>
```

Apparently, It has more noise than the first format. The components are dynamically loaded in my application. Therefore the "AnyComponentName" and "AnyConfigName" are variables.
My question is, is it possible to write a custom `ConfigurationSection`.. etc implementations to parse the first format?
Or in another way, Is it possible to use variables for tag names?

If yes, could you please provide examples in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to adapt `ConfigurationSection` to (virtually) any format, including the XML schema you provided.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20548/Creating-a-Custom-Configuration-Section-in-C) is an article on how to correctly implement it.

You will need to implement three classes to read your configuration data: `ConfigurationElement`, `ConfigurationElementCollection` and `ConfigurationSection`.

Comment: The article you linked uses something inline with the second schema that I mentioned in my question. I need to use variables for tag names I've made some changes to the question to clarify the requirement. Anyway, Thanks. Your answer suggests me it is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you brief sample of one **web config** file from Nopcommerce 1.8 open source project, let's see if it helps.

```
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <section name="NopConfig" type="NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Configuration.NopConfig, Nop.BusinessLogic" requirePermission="false"/>
        </configSections>
        <NopConfig>
            <SqlServer ConnectionStringName="NopSqlConnection"/>
            <Cache Enabled="True"/>
            <ScheduleTasks>
                <Thread seconds="60">
                    <task name="ClearCache" type="NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Caching.ClearCacheTask, Nop.BusinessLogic" enabled="true" stopOnError="false"/>
                    <task name="KeepAlive" type="NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Utils.KeepAliveTask, Nop.BusinessLogic" enabled="true" stopOnError="false" path="keepalive/ping.ashx"/>
                </Thread>
                <Thread seconds="43200">
                    <task name="KeepFedexDelivery" type="NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Utils.KeepFedexDeliveryTask, Nop.BusinessLogic" enabled="true" stopOnError="false" path="keepalive/GetDeleiveredDate.ashx"/>
                </Thread>
            </ScheduleTasks>
        </NopConfig>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You have two 'ConfigElement' implementations for SqlServer and Cache, and a 'ConfigurationElementCollection' implementation for the ScheduleTasks, right? My tag names are variables. Anyway, Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, In this Sample XML it is right. In my original file I had a lot of configuration properties and collection of properties with many sections(more than 15).